# How to rate limit per day in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to rate limit per day instead of per minute. How do I do it?

```
if (RateLimiter::remaining('send-message:'.$user->id, $perMinute = 5)) {
    RateLimiter::hit('send-message:'.$user->id);
 
    // Send message...
}
```

Comment: @BagusTesa But I though the `5` there meant the rate limit?

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about [rate limiting requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#rate-limiting) or the general abstraction of [rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting)

Comment: @apokryfos The abstraction.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php) is the source of that. Some have `$decayMinutes` parameters (other curiously do not) so if you can work with ones that do you can use `1440` as decay minutes (minutes in a day)

Comment: If for instance, you said that the limit was 0.1 per minute, you would only be able to send one message per 10 minutes which is not what I guess you want.  You probably want to send as quick as you like until the quota is used ?  Probably better with a counter.

Answer (score 4):

Just add another limiter in `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` inside `configureRateLimiting` function

like so;

```
protected function configureRateLimiting() {

    //Default Limiter
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
    });


    //Your Limiter - limit 10 request per day    
    RateLimiter::for('day', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perDay(10)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

then you can use it in a middleware for `throttle` implementation

e.g.

```
// on group routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:day'], function () {
    Route::get('/limit-test', function( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        return $request;
    })->name('rate.test');
});

// with single route
Route::get('/limit-test', function( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::remaining( $request->ip, 10);
    return $request;
})->middleware('throttle:day');


//or inside a controller
public function __construct() {

    //All methods
    $this->middleware('throttle:day');

    // or on specific method
    //$this->middleware('throttle:day')->only('whatEverFunction'); 
    
    // or all method except
    //$this->middleware('throttle:day')->except('whatEverFunction');
}
```

If you check the response header, you should be able to see

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 10
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you can do:

```
$success = RateLimiter::attempt('send-message:'.$user->id, $maxAttempts, function () {
   // Send message
}, 1440);
if (!$success) {
   // Rate limit hit..
}
```